# What is the proper way to write C++ Setters for members which are pointers to other objects so that there are no memory leaks or crashes?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have searched a lot on this. But may be I am not getting the phrasing right.

Consider,

```
Class A {};

Class B {

public:
    A* getA();
    void setA(A *aVarParam);

private:
    A *aVar;
};
```

Now since aVar is a member variable of class B I want to ensure that it stays alive as long the corresponding object of class B exists.

So the options I see here are,

1. Make a deep copy of aVarParam and hold a pointer to it.
2. Use something like a Boost shared pointer.

Both of which seems either too much work or ugly syntax. Am I missing something here? Do all C++ programs use one of these 2 options?

More Explanation:

Ok many of you wanted to see an example of how I am using it. Actually I wanted a general purpose strategy kind of answer. Hence the original example. Here is the example I am trying to use:

```
#ifndef DBSCHEMA_H
#define DBSCHEMA_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "dbtable.h"

namespace models {

    class DbSchema
    {
    public:
        explicit DbSchema();

        boost::shared_ptr<std::string> getSchemaName() const;
        void setSchemaName(const boost::shared_ptr<std::string> schemaName);

        std::vector<models::DbTable> getTableList() const;
        void setTableList(const std::vector<models::DbTable> tableList);
    private:
        boost::shared_ptr<std::string> schemaName_;
        std::vector<models::DbTable> tableList_;
    };

}


#endif // DBSCHEMA_H
```

Here the class DbSchema is being used as a thin model which will direct the UI (A QT application). And there will be many Schema Builders which will actually communicate with different databases to fill the DBSchema objects which the UI will use.

I hope this clears up about what I am trying to achieve. I am not a C++ programmer. After programming Java, Objective-C, PHP and JavaScript for years, I am trying to satisfy an itch to write a "real C++" application.

Comment: Use a [`std::shared_ptr<A>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/) instead!

Comment: You need to decide who owns the resource that `aVar` points to. That should tell you which option is correct; deep-copy (`std::unique_ptr`), `std::shared_ptr`, or non-owning raw pointer.

Comment: Please present a more complete, realistic example.  Right now, your question is completely ambiguous.  Generally, we avoid storing pointers, if possible.  There are, however, a variety of reasons to store a pointer, and you need to expound upon what your reason is (which a realistic example would do) in order for us to advise you on the proper handling of your situation.

Comment: Rule of three (C++ programming) maybe useful to you

Comment: A shared pointer around a std::string looks plain wrong - and why no shared_ptr<std::vector<models::DbTable>> ?

Comment: @DieterLücking About shared_ptr for the vector makes more sense now as I look at it. However what are the technical reasons one should not use shared pointers for std::sting? It will be great if you could point me to a technical article in this regard. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the sake of the question, I'll assume that you have a genuine reason for storing a pointer, rather than the object itself. However, if your real code is similar to the example, then there is no good reason for storing a pointer to a string.

The third option is to take ownership of the object. Before C++11, this was tricky to achieve without the danger of leaks or dangling pointers, but these days we have move semantics and `unique_ptr`, a smart pointer to handle single transferable ownership semantics.

```
#include <memory>

class B {
public:
    void setA(std::unique_ptr<A> aVarParam) {
        aVar = std::move(aVarParam);
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<A> aVar;
};

std::unique_ptr<A> myA(new A);
assert(myA);                   // we own the object
b.setA(std::move(myA));        // transfer ownership
assert(!myA);                  // we no longer own it
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want B to own the object A then it is not clear
to a user who owns the object after a function like

`A* getA();`

who should delete the object?

even though there is additional syntax using a `shared_ptr`
would make it clear to the user of your class who owns the
object.

`std::shared_ptr<A> getA();`

If you otoh want to pass the object along to somebody else 
use `std::unique_ptr` instead.

there is not much overhead at all adding this and it makes
your code easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

I think the first question you need to answer is a matter of conception.
Who's supposed to own the resource, and who's using it.

If these two are the same, a unique_ptr seems appropriate, if not, the shared_ptr/weak_ptr could be appropriate, but again, without knowing more about your whole problem, seems hard to give a definite answer.

For example, if your class is merely using the resource without owning it, the resource should be stored with a shared_ptr somewhere, and your class should only hold a weak_ptr to it, and lock it only when it wants to use it, and be prepared to handle the case where the resource has been deleted (if that should happen).

edit: after seeing your edit
Seeing your code like that, I don't see why you would need a pointer, just use a classic std::string and all will be fine... (unless I'm missing something, but that raises the question: why a pointer?)